# How do I change polymorphed variable into the child type?

Tags: c#

I am making a program that uses polymorphism but in a list. Now when I am using the values in the list, I already determined which are child and parent through an if statement, but the issue is that I cannot access any of the child's attributes. Any suggestions?  (Sample code below)

```
//In Class one
public List<Parent> parent; 
parent.Add(new Child());


//In Class two
if (parent[0] is Child)
{
   //treats it as parent
   Console.WriteLine(parent[0].name());
}
```

In the code above, the attribute name is public but in child's class, so I cannot access any of the child's attributes because it does not know it is a child. Is there a way I can make the object a child? The list has to use the polymorphism because there are multiple different child classes that need to be in one list.

Comment: you need a class cast: `((Child) parent).name()`

Comment: thanks!!!!! definitely helped!

Comment: Welcome. I added as answer then with slightly more detail

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `as` keyword. This is a safe cast which returns null when the cast is not possible.

```
Child child = obj as Child;
if (child!=null)
{
    child.childMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With inheritance and polymorphism, a Parent object reference that points to a Child object can only access Parent methods at runtime. However it can be cast and the Child methods called.  `((Child) obj).childMethod();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get at the child methods through casting, like this:

```
//In Class one
public List<Parent> parent; 
parent.Add(new Child());

//In Class two
Child parentAsChild = parent[0] as Child;
if (parentAsChild != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(parentAsChild.name());
}
```

The `as` operator performs a "defensive" cast, which returns null if `parent[0]` cannot be cast to a `Child` object.

Be careful though - you're circumventing the purpose of polymorphism by doing this.  The whole point of polymorphism is that you don't have to do typechecking and casting - the child class should override any behavior that differs from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Either cast the object to `Child` after checking its type:

```
//In Class one
public List<Parent> parent; 
parent.Add(new Child());

//In Class two
if (parent[0] is Child)
{
   var child = (Child) parent[0];
   Console.WriteLine(child.name());
}
```

or cast the object to `Child` before checking its type:

```
//In Class one
public List<Parent> parent; 
parent.Add(new Child());


//In Class two
var child = parent[0] as Child;
if (child != null)
{
   //treats it as parent
   Console.WriteLine(child.name());
}
```

This sort of casting should be avoided whenever possible. Consider using an interface to define the API you'll need to consume, or defining a virtual member on `Parent`.